# Lost editing feature in Photoshop Elements

Tags: windows-7, photoshop-elements

I am using photo shop elements 10 in Windows 7 & have several family videos which I lost when my computer crashed.

I have saved my videos to disc but photo shop will not allow editing to continue with my unfinished projects.

I am able to play them from file, but the editing feature is non existent.

If this feature using photo shop isn't retrievable, any advice as to other
programs that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You say they are saved on disk - Do you mean CD/DVD?

If so, by default these files will be marked read only.

I'd suggest you copy the files to a local disk, maybe your desktop or somewhere similar.

Once you've done this, right click the file, select properties and unclick 'read only' then try opening these files directly in elements.